# Comment traduire « card skimmer » (méthode de fraude au distributeur de billets) ?

Tags: terminologie

Dans le contexte de la fraude aux distributeurs de billets, un « *card skimmer* » (en anglais) est un dispositif double permettant d'enregistrer en vidéo le code saisi par l'usager, et de copier la piste magnétique de la carte insérée.

[image: card skimmer scheme]

Je ne sais pas s'il existe une expression établie en français pour désigner cela, et les traductions que j'arrive à imaginer me semblent trop peu spécifiques : « fraude à la copie de carte », par exemple, est à la fois très générique et un peu long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un collègue qui a travaillé dans la carte à puce propose un *espion* pour le dispositif (le *skimmer*) lui-même. Un espion, comme son nom l'indique, espionne les communications, et peut éventuellement les modifier au passage (le terme générique pour ce genre d'attaque sur un système sécurisé en français est *man-in-the-middle*, prononcé « mane ine zeu midole »). Pour ce qui est de copier une carte, le terme technique est *clonage* (et *cloning* en anglais, au passage).

Pour le type de fraude, je ne sais pas de terme consacré (je n'ai pas de contacts dans le milieu qui la pratique). La base [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/skim.html) suggère « [fraude par clonage](http://caissespopulairesacadiennes.com/contenu.cfm?id=1302) » voire « [écrémage des cartes](http://bankers.cba.ca/contents/files/submissions/sub_20090603_01_fr.pdf) ».

Comment: le skimmer est appelé dans le milieu policier/délinquant un "collier" si mes souvenirs sont bons.

Answer (score 5):

J'ai déjà lu « DAB piégé » ou « Distributeur piégé » ou « Fraude à la carte bancaire ».

Comment: Le problème est que cet « écumoire » (je ne pense pas que le terme soit d'usage courant dans ce sens en français) désigne une technique particulière. Le « collet marseillais » est une autre technique pour piéger un DAB.

Comment: @Un francophone, la traduction « écumoire » n'est, à ma connaissance, pas utilisée. On parlera probablement de  « Dispositif de copie de carte ».

Answer (score 2):

A ma connaissance, il n'y a pas d'expression consacrée pour cela en français. On parlera de *faux dispositif de retrait d'argent*, ou encore de *distributeur modifié de façon frauduleuse*, par exemple.